# Remove UIElements from TabBar View Controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` in which I have 3 `UIViewControllers` (3 tabs). 
I want to remove specific elements from each `UIViewController` view when the whole `UITabBarController` will disappear.

Is there any way to do this? I cannot use `viewWillDisappear:` in each `UIViewController` because this will remove these elements when the tab changes also.

Is there any way to handle this into `viewWillDisappear:` into TabBarController.m file?

Comment: You want to do that when you are poping your view controller ?

Comment: Yes. TabBarController is into a navigationController. I want to do that when backButton will be pressed from each of the tree tabs.

Comment: U can do itrate through yourTabBar.viewControllers to get all viewController and perform specific selctor and that to remove those component from other view also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be taking reference of viewController getting displayed. Use those references on back button to remove your specific elements from your controllers.

Hope you get it. Feel free to ask if any concerns ?

Or, you can use these delegate methods of `UINavigationController` :

```
// Called when the navigation controller shows a new top view controller via a push, pop or setting of the view controller stack.
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your time Samkit. The method that is called when the back button is pressed is into only one of the ViewControllers and it just calls popViewController. How to take the remaining viewControllers and remove the elements tha i want?

Comment: See, the problem is when you are popping of the thing..all the references of your viewControllers in memory will be lost...So, you can set some BOOL variable to check at the pushing to TabBarcontroller. Once you are again coming to tabBar remove the views from controllers depending on your requirement

Comment: The solution was to call a custom method for each viewController into back button method and remove the elements that i want. Thanks Samkit.

Comment: For any issues ..contact me @mrsamkitjain@gmail.com